# Titanium SetImage in Addevenlistener

Tags: imageview, titanium

```
var like = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image: 'images/liked.png',
    left: 270,
    top: 5,
    height: 30,
    width: 30
});

like.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    like.setImage('images/unliked.png');
    alert('like pressed');
});
```

This is my code.. What I'm trying to do is to change image of imageview to another image when image is clicked.. But it doesn't change and I really don't know what to do..I miss objective c so much..

Answer (score 0):

Do this in evenlistener

```
like.image='images/unliked.png';


    //CustomData[i].liked=false;
    //CustomData[i]=    {flag:CustomData[i].flag,title:CustomData[i].title,creator:CustomData[i].creator,channel:CustomData[i].channel,liked:false};    
    //alert('like pressed');

  alert('like pressed');
```

Thanks

Comment: Plz checkout the spelling of your image

Comment: Wahhab, I've checked. I think I need to refresh the tablerow to refresh data but I don't know how to do that either..

Comment: You don't need to refresh TableRow when you are changing it's content. Post more detailed code example so we can see what's wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before, the problem is not in the code, I faced it on android but it was working fine with iOS.

For android, you have to make a workaround, try one of the next solutions:

1. Remove the imageView from the TableViewRow children and then add it again in the imageViewListener.
2. Remove the tableViewRow from the Table View and then add it.

This work around forces the window to redraw its views and that will include the new image.

If you need any help with the code for those solutions, just ask.